# Getting "cannot set property Error of undefined" when trying to run the .js output of a simple hello world clojurescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, clojure, clojurescript

I'm compiling:

```
(ns example.hello)
(js/console.log "Hello from ClojureScript!")
```

With this configuration:

```
(defproject lein-cljsbuild-example "1.2.3"
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "0.2.9"]]
  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{
        :source-path "src-cljs"
        :compiler {
          :output-to "war/javascripts/mainz.js"  ; default: main.js in current directory
          ;:optimizations :simple
          :target :nodejs
          ;:pretty-print true
          }}]})
```

Which outputs a file that is too big to put here, but gives the error:

```
goog.debug.Error = function(opt_msg) {
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'Error' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/Clojure/cljstest/war/javascripts/mainz.js:503:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Comment: looks like goog.debug is undefined.. are you including the proper file?

Comment: @lostsource what is the proper file? I thought the generated .js was auto-suficient. Perhaps it is missing some node.js extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has been solved by reinstalling leiningen and doing a clean build.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the project config you give, your `:optimizations :simple` clause is commented out. This means that it will not have any Google Closure optimizations, meaning that the output JavaScript will *not* be in one sufficient file, but broken into many files. Which also means you must explicitly include `base.js` from the Google Closure library.

It looks like that's what's happening here, although there might be other stuff going on as well... I'm actually not that familiar with the node.js output for ClojureScript.